# Get-Counter not accepting array created from SQL

Tags: sql-server, powershell, perfmon

When I try and generate an array from a SQL output, although it's the same data type and content, perfmon doesn't accept these values, whereas it does for a manually created a list. So the first call for Get-Counter returns an error message as seen below, where as the second call with a manually created list works correctly. How do I resolve this?

```
 Get-Counter : Internal performance counter API call failed. Error: c0000bc4.
```

At line:26 char:9

```
    $SQLQueryGetCounters  = "
    DECLARE @PerfmonCounterList VARCHAR(MAX) 
    SELECT 
        TOP 2
            PerfmonCounter
    FROM
        Perfmon.PerfmonCounterList"

    $SQLQueryGetCounters  = "
    DECLARE @PerfmonCounterList VARCHAR(MAX) 
    SELECT top 2
        ' `"' +PerfmonCounter + '`"' ItemValue 
    FROM
        Perfmon.PerfmonCounterList " 
    $Counters =   @(Invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance Localhost -Database "DatabaseMonitoring" -Query $SQLQueryGetCounters )| select-object -expand ItemValue
    $List = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@() # New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object] # [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()

    foreach ($Item in $Counters)
        {
            $List.Add($Item)
        }

    $List = $List.ToArray()

    Get-Counter -Counter $List

     $List = "\DATABASE(*)\DATABASE CACHE % HIT","\DATABASE(*)\DATABASE CACHE SIZE (MB)"

     Get-Counter -Counter $List
```

Comment: `c0000bc4` could be `invalid path`. What counters are you querying for? Do they exist?

Comment: Hi @LievenKeersmaekers, the counters are as they appear in the manually created list. The list was created by manually copying counters from the output

Comment: Can you post `$list.GetType()` before both the `Get-Counter` methods? Can you post `$list` before both the `Get-Counter` methods?

Comment: It's  System.Array both times

Comment: and the content?

Comment: and the type of the items in the list? `$list[0].GetType()`. There has to be a difference somewhere

Comment: These all return System.Object across all items

Comment: This is really in the wrong forum as the issue is with a PowerShell command, and SQL Server isn't really involved at that point.  You might want to post it in StackOverflow or Server Fault.  I would recommend trying to repro this by creating text file instead of a database so that it is easy for someone else to repro.